# lua memory management

Tags: lua

How can we free the lua stack?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is definitely programming related and I don't se any issues with the language used or anything.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 15):

Why do you want to do this?

If you need to remove all elements in Lua stack, you should call `lua_settop(L, 0)`. To quote [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_settop):

> `void lua_settop (lua_State *L, int index);`
>
> Accepts any acceptable index, or 0, and sets the stack top to this index. If the new top is larger than the old one, then the new elements are filled with nil. If index is 0, then all stack elements are removed.

This would subject all elements in stack to garbage collection. Call `lua_gc(LUA_GC_COLLECT)` afterwards to do garbage collection. If you really need to collect all collectable garbage, call it in a loop, until value, returned by `lua_gc(LUA_GCCOUNT)`, would stay the same.

Note that (AFAIK) you can't free space, allocated for the stack itself — unless, of course, you call `lua_close()`.

Comment: I think you meant: lua_settop(L, 0).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the only way I know for freeing the whole lua stack is calling lua_close on the lua_State instance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`lua_remove`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_remove)?  I just skimmed over the manual, not sure if there's a "clear whole stack" function.

> `void lua_remove (lua_State *L, int index);`
>
> Removes the element at the given valid index, shifting down the elements above this index to fill the gap. Cannot be called with a pseudo-index, because a pseudo-index is not an actual stack position.

Answer (score 1):

`lua_settop(L, 0);` should work.
Call lua_gc() then. This won't free all space,
**whole** stack will be cleared when you will close lua state.

Answer (score 0):

If you have put e.g. 5 elements on the stack you no longer need, you can remove them with [lua_pop](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pop):

```
lua_pop(l, 5) -- removes the 5 topmost elements from the stack
```

Otherwise, you might want to use [lua_settop](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_settop) or lua_remove as already suggested.

Since Lua is automatically garbage collected, the actual memory occupied will take a while to be freed, so you need to call the garbage collector explicitely if you want to have it removed instantly.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you don't have to. For example, in a function you might push 5 values, then return 3, to say you are returning 3 values. The extra 2 values will be freed automatically, since the stack size is adjusted to what you said. (This avoids errors where you say you are returning a different number of values than actually pushed.)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a table or array as variable storage you could set the key to nil by doing

```
a[variable key]=nil
```

I read that if you call a key that does not exist in the table/array it will return nil, nil being a state of no data, variable, or state, I have always assumed that it, in a way deletes or clears out the data in the key